# httpwebrequest and javascript

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

When i try to load the following page:

```
http://www.manta.com/c/mm0mg7z/law-office-of-wendy-kazel
```

with a httpwebrequest (i use the below code)

```
try {
    HttpWebRequest _wReq;
    HttpWebResponse _wResp;
    System.IO.StreamReader _sr;
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding _enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    _wReq = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://www.manta.com/c/mm0mg7z/law-office-of-wendy-kazel");
    _wReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
    _wReq.Timeout = 20000;
    _wReq.ReadWriteTimeout = 20000;

    _wReq.Referer = "http://www.manta.com";

    _wResp = (HttpWebResponse) _wReq.GetResponse();
    _sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(_wResp.GetResponseStream());
    _html = _sr.ReadToEnd();
    _sr.Close();
    _wResp.Close();

} catch (WebException ee) {

}
```

I get the following returned html from manta

```
Oops.
Before you can move on, please activate JavaScript.
```

It doesn't always happend but most of the time.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I think that the website depends on JavaScript, what does _html stand for?

Comment: _html is the html source from the request

Comment: Sorry, I meant that how is _html used? If _html is a variable, how did you create it? Is there a specific code you used to create this variable/object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTTP Webrequest **cannot execute** client-end scripts. Javascript needs that the script be executed, page be loaded and the **DOM be constructed** for various operations to be performed.

The webrequests & responses just download the resource, and do not process or execute it in anyway.
You are better off using a **WebBrowserControl** in this case.